# WIX4 Bundle does not show up in "Programs and Features" after installation

Tags: bundle, wix4

I upgraded a WIX 3.11 bundle to WIX 4, now (after some other troubles) everything is working again. The only problem left is, that the bundle show up in "Programs and Features" during installation, but as soon, as the "Done" dialog appears, it disappears from "Programs and Features".

As I understand this should only be the case when both Bundle arguments "DisableModify" and "DisableRemove" are set to "yes". I left out both, which should default them to "no" (I also tried to set them explicitly to "no"). During installation I can click on the dot menu on the right side and see the two menus are enabled. Also setting one of them to "yes" the corresponding menu is greyed out so I'm pretty sure they are really set to "no".

I read in an older question addressing a similar problem, that there is the "SystemComponent" key under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{Bundle GUID} which, set to 1, hides it. But my bundle does not appear in the registry at all. It's 64bit, but I also checked WOW6432Node just to be sure.

Maybe someone can help me with that.

Thanks in advance,
Christoph

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself. There seems to be a non-documented (at least I could not find it) change in behavior for bundles. In wix 3.11 the bundle was shown in "Programs and Features", even if all Exe/MSI entries in chain had the attribute permanent="yes". In WIX 4 at least one hast to have permanent="no", otherwise it is removed from "Programs and Features".

For us the old behavior was better, as it was documented, that the bundle was installed on a computer.